# Improving my PowersShell script which exports list of timestamps of files in a folder to a CSV file

Tags: powershell, timestamp, windows-10

For now I have this piece of code:

```
$items = @()
$OutputFilePath = "c:\csv\text1.csv"

dir -Force -Recurse | foreach { 
    $FullName  = $_.FullName            
    $Creation  = $_.CreationTimeUtc    
    $Modified  = $_.LastWriteTimeUtc   
    $Accessed  = $_.LastAccessTimeUtc  
    $Size      = $_.Length
    $Atributes = $_.Attributes

    $i = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FullName           -Value $FullName
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreatedDateUtc     -Value $Creation
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreatedTimeUtc     -Value $Creation.TimeOfDay
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreatedTicksUtc    -Value $Creation.Ticks
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ModifiedDateUtc    -Value $Modified 
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ModifiedTimeUtc    -Value $Modified.TimeOfDay
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ModifiedTicksUtc   -Value $Modified.Ticks
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AccessedDateUtc    -Value $Accessed 
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AccessedTimeUtc    -Value $Accessed.TimeOfDay
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AccessedTicksUtc   -Value $Accessed.Ticks
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Size               -Value $Size
    $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Atributes          -Value $Atributes
    $items += $i
}

$FileExists = Test-Path $OutputFilePath
if ($FileExists -eq $False) {
    $items | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFilePath -NoClobber -Encoding UTF8
} else {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The output file already exists. Please delete or rename it to continue." ,"Error", 0, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
}
```

It gives me the list of UTC timestamps of all objects in a folder and subfolder. (I find UTC timestamps much more useful than non-UTC timestamps because I work on the concept of Virtual Reality weather timelapse service and I understand that errors at days when daylight saving time begins and ends wouldn't be acceptable so I say these errors are also unacceptable in other cases.) What I'm missing are the timestamps of parent folder itself.

How could I include timestamps of parent folder too?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `Get-Item` on the current directory:

```
$(Get-Item .; Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Force) | ForEach-Object {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Ansgar Wiechers's answer that solves the problem:

- Create PSObject in one go instead of adding the members one by one which is slow
- Pipe the output without recreating the array in each iteration which is slow

---

```
$OutputFilePath = "c:\csv\text1.csv"

if (Test-Path $OutputFilePath) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
        "The output file already exists. Please delete or rename it to continue.",
        "Error",
        0,
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error
    )
} else {
    $(gi .; dir -Force -Recurse) | %{ 
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            FullName         = $_.FullName
            CreatedDateUtc   = $_.CreationTimeUtc
            CreatedTimeUtc   = $_.CreationTimeUtc.TimeOfDay
            CreatedTicksUtc  = $_.CreationTimeUtc.Ticks
            ModifiedDateUtc  = $_.LastWriteTimeUtc 
            ModifiedTimeUtc  = $_.LastWriteTimeUtc.TimeOfDay
            ModifiedTicksUtc = $_.LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks
            AccessedDateUtc  = $_.LastAccessTimeUtc 
            AccessedTimeUtc  = $_.LastAccessTimeUtc.TimeOfDay
            AccessedTicksUtc = $_.LastAccessTimeUtc.Ticks
            Size             = $_.Length
            Atributes        = $_.Atributes
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFilePath -NoClobber -Encoding UTF8
}
```

I've used aliases (`gi` for `Get-Item` and `%` for `foreach`) since you're fond of them.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already noticed how slow it is and I wondered whether I will have to switch to some other programming language which I don't understand yet.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, unfortunately. It displays lots of error messages:

'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:12 char:9
+         [PSObject]@{
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull'

Comment: See the updated code, there was an error I've just fixed.

Comment: Thank you again. Now the fixed code seems to work much better than my original code. I will have to test it again in different conditions and then tell you the results.

Comment: OK, the issue with characters outside of 7-bit ASCII which are replaced by question marks is not there. The parent directory is properly recognized, even if it's root directory. But I get two errors with too long file paths. Now how I could resolve it too...

Comment: dir : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At line:11 char:13
+     $(gi .; dir -Force -Recurse) | %{
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Data-2909201...oo much privacy:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand